# Killing buffers whose names start with a particular string

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Here's my problem:
I use Emacs and get lots of buffers that are pretty useless all the time, like *Messages* or *Completions*.

I want to bind \C-y to close all buffers that start with * except for *shell* (and *shell* < k >) buffers.

To do that, I'd like to add some Emacs-Lisp in my .emacs file:

```
(defun string-prefix s1 s2
  (if (> (string-length s1) (string-length s2)) nil
    (string=? s1 (substring s2 0 (string-length s1))) ))

(defun curry2
  (lambda (f)
    (lambda (x)
      (lambda (y)
    (f x y) ))))

(defun filter
  (lambda (f l)
    (if (null? l) '()
      (let ((rest (cdr l)))
    (if (f (car l)) (cons (car l) rest)
      rest) ))))


(defun kill-useless (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (map 'kill-buffer
       (filter
    (not ((curry2 string-prefix) "*shell*"))
    (list-buffers)
    ) ))

(global-set-key "\C-y" 'kill-useless)
```

I've already tested `string-prefix` and `curry2` using Scheme and `filter` seems pretty straightforward.
Sadly I just can't get `kill-useless` to work properly.

It says `filter: Invalid function: (curry2 string-prefix)`.

Now, the thing is I kind of suck at Emacs-Lisp, I don't really use any Lisp except Scheme, and in Scheme (MIT), this works:

```
(filter ((curry2 string-prefix?) "*shell") '("*shell*" "*sh22" "eel"))
;Value 5: ("*shell*")
```

I'd like:

1. a way to fix my code
2. suggestions on how to do this in a different way

Thanks!

Comment: The `*Message*` buffer is a useful one: every time Emacs tell you something, it let it there, so you can for example copy and paste it to google to find a solution on google. Beware also that when you will probably use some mode (like magit) who will use such buffer in a useful way.

Comment: Yes, I ended up keeping that buffer too. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternate approach:

```
(require 'cl)

(defun is-useless-buffer (buffer)
  (let ((name (buffer-name buffer)))
    (and (= ?* (aref name 0))
         (not (string-match "^\\*shell\\*" name)))))

(defun kill-useless-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (loop for buffer being the buffers
        do (and (is-useless-buffer buffer) (kill-buffer buffer))))
```

Comment: I like this approach the most. I've also added in a check to keep the \*Messages* buffer. Congrats Sean! You win :)

Also, what does `(require 'cl)` do exactly?

Comment: It brings in Emacs's Common Lisp package, which is where the (extremely handy) "loop" macro lives.  The whole package is very useful; the first line in my .emacs file is (require 'cl).  See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Then you can add some logging to see if the buffers you think are useless really are, according to `is-useless-buffer`.  For example, you could change the `do (and ...)` part to `do (message "Buffer %s %s useless" (buffer-name buffer) (if (is-useless-buffer buffer) "is" "is not"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, @Sean. I am no elisp programmer. For me all useless buffers would be basically all except internal Emacs buffers (starting with *). How to implement this?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein If it wasn't clear, after executing the above code (for example by having it in your startup file when you run Emacs), you still need to run the `kill-useless-buffers` command by typing `M-x` (hold down meta/alt and press `x`), `kill-useless-buffers`, and the Return key.  Also, there will be no visible indication that the buffers were killed, unless you happen to be looking at one when you run the command.  I just started Emacs, created some buffers named `*foo*`, `*bar*`, and `*baz*`, then ran that command, and those buffers were deleted.

Comment: To change this code to delete everything except buffers whose names start with an asterisk, just change the body of the `is-useless-buffer` function (everything from the opening parenthesis on the second line to the next-to-last closing parenthesis on the last line) to `(string-match-p (rx string-start (not (any "*"))) (buffer-name buffer))`.  Then you'll need to evaluate the revised definition to make it take effect, most easily by pressing control-meta-X while the cursor is inside the function.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 30):

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `kill-matching-buffers` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> kill-matching-buffers is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `files.el'.
>
> (kill-matching-buffers REGEXP &optional INTERNAL-TOO)
>
> Kill buffers whose name matches the specified REGEXP.
>   The optional second argument indicates whether to kill internal buffers too.

Comment: +1 for built-in function although an actual example of how to use it would have been far more helpful.

Comment: It keeps asking if I want to close every buffer though (even if unmodified) - is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Yeah, the UI of that function is really bad. In effect one starts pressing `y` really quick and when a **modified** buffer shows up you've killed it before noticing the question is slightly different...

Comment: @Zitrax If you do C-h f on kill-matching-buffers, it gives more details. You can avoid the prompt for closing every buffer with something like (kill-matching-bufers REGEXP nil t) (its the t that does this - nil is for setting internal-too to nil (you can change this if required - check the docs on what each optional does)

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind elisp isn't scheme, or even common lisp.  The syntax and semantics are different.  For example, `defun` requires a parameters list surrounded by parentheses.  Also, currying isn't really possible in elisp.

Fortunately, elisp has builtins for most of what you want to do.  For `string-prefix` you can use the `string-prefix-p` builtin.  For `filter`, you can use `remove-if-not`, or `remove-if` for the inverse.

For the currying you can use the `apply-partially` builtin function.  To get a function that matches strings with the prefix `"*shell*"`, try something like this:

```
(apply-partially 'string-prefix-p "*shell*")
```

You can use it like this:

```
(mapcar
 (apply-partially 'string-prefix-p "*shell*")
 '("*shell*" "foo" "*shell*<2>"))

; results in
(t nil t)

(require 'cl) ; for remove-if
(remove-if
 (apply-partially 'string-prefix-p "*shell*")
 '("*shell*" "foo" "*shell*<2>"))

; results in
("foo")
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I gave the _answer_ to the person who gave me a working solution. Trying to fiddle around to get this work would not have been too much fun!

Answer (score 0):

It can be a good idea to see what you will delete before deleting it, to play safe.

In **Icicles**, by default `C-x k` is a multi-command that you can use to kill any number of buffers that match your minibuffer input.  In this case, you would type `* TAB` to see all buffer names starting with `*` as completion candidates.

You can then narrow the matches, in several ways. When all of the matches remaining are what you want, hit `C-!` to delete all of those buffers.

In the case you presented, you do not want to delete buffers named `*shell...`. So after `* TAB` you would hit `S-SPC` and then enter another pattern to match: `shell`, then `S-TAB`. That narrows to only the `*shell...` buffers that you do *not* want to kill. You then hit `C-~` to subtract those matches (complement). That leaves all of the buffers except the shell buffers. Hit `C-!` and they're all killed.

You can also kill individual buffers by just control-clicking their names in `*Completions*`: `C-mouse-2`.

More generally, in **Icicles** *every* multi-command that reads a buffer name lets you use `S-delete` (Shift + the Delete key) to kill buffer candidates.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_More_About_Multi-Commands

Answer (score 0):

I found `kill-matching-functions` prompted me for unmodified buffers, which isn't what I wanted. The function below will kill buffers matching a prefix (as in the title of the question). Not exactly what you wanted, but maybe people like me who come here from Google will find this useful.

```
(require 'cl)
(defun kill-buffers-with-prefix (prefix)
  "Kill buffers whose names start with the given prefix"
  (interactive "sPrefix to kill: ")
  (loop for buffer in (buffer-list)
        do (if (string-prefix-p prefix (buffer-name buffer))
               (kill-buffer buffer))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill all other buffers

```
(defun px-kill-other-buffers ()
  "Kill all other buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list))))
```

To search the beginning of a string

```
(defun string-starts-with-p (string prefix)
    "Return t if STRING starts with prefix."
    (and
     (string-match (rx-to-string `(: bos ,prefix) t) string)
     t))
```